# Prove by definition that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e\sin(4x)}{x^2 + 2\sinh(x)} = 2e$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

how are you?

I'm stuck on this limit about a week. I already tried the transformations of $\sinh(x)$, but I can't find a $\delta$ so $$\left| \frac{e\sin(4x)}{x^2 + 2\sinh(x)} - 2e \right| < \epsilon$$

Please, help :(

edit1: I was doing this:

$$\left| \frac{e\sin(4x)}{x^2 + 2\sinh(x)} - 2e \right| \Rightarrow \left| \frac{2e\sin(4x)}{2(x^2 + 2\sinh(x))} - 2e \right|$$

$$\Rightarrow 2e \left| \frac{\sin(4x)}{2(x^2 + 2\sinh(x))} - 1 \right|$$

Since $ \sin(4x) \leq |x|+1$,

$$2e \left| \frac{\sin(4x)}{2(x^2 + 2\sinh(x))} - 1 \right| \leq 2e \left| \frac{|x|+1}{2(x^2 + 2\sinh(x))} - 1 \right|$$

I don't know if this will help.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I think verifying that limit using the definition will be very difficult. Are you sure that's required. If not, I suggest writing down the power series expansions of the various terms. Then ordinary algebra will help you see the zeroth order term.

Comment: Please add your attempts to the question.

Comment: Mate,It will be nearly impossible to deduce the limit from definition.Why not use L'HOSPITAL'S rule?

Comment: It's a real analysis question. Use L'Hospital is like using cheat. There must be some function that limits this monster and converges. ( i think )

Comment: Are you allowed to use the well-known limits of $\sin x /x$ and $\sinh x/x$ at $x=0$?

Comment: @Gary yes, but how this will help?

Comment: @EthanBolker  Thanks :) I will try

Comment: You may write your fraction as $$
4e\frac{{\sin (4x)}}{{4x}}\frac{1}{{x + 2\frac{{\sinh x}}{x}}}.
$$
From the known limits, this will tend to $$
4e \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{{0 + 2 \cdot 1}} = 2e.
$$

Comment: @Gary I think, if i prove the known limits by " $\epsilon - \delta$ " arguments before (i'm sure i can find it somewhere ) i can use this. Maybe not the most  beautiful proof, but still a proof. Thanks :)